# Options for preserving state

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, seo

I have a page where I need to check for the presence of a cookie and then perform a redirect.

I have the code written (ASP.NET) to detect the cookie and perform a redirect. Pseudo-code:

```
HttpCookie myCookie = Request.Cookies.Get("theCookie");
if(myCookie == null)
{
 myCookie = new HttpCookie("theCookie","myValue")
 response.Redirect("page.aspx"); //Redirect to check for the presence of the cookie
}

More code...
```

When the user has cookies enabled, this approach works fine. When they have cookies disabled, however, they wind up stuck in an infinite loop (the page attempts to create the cookie, redirects, sees no cookie, then redirects again, ad infinitum). Most human users are probably going to be OK, but this will probably do a number on the site's SEO ratings.

I've wracked my brain for solutions, and since cookies are out of the question, that leaves viewstate and querystrings.

Because I've got to do a redirect, I think I'm stuck with querystrings. The problem is in order to detect whether a page has already been hit, I need to append a querystring to prevent the redirect from kicking in again.

Can anyone think of a way to accomplish this (preventing a redirect) without using cookies, viewstate, or querystrings? I think the answer is probably no...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a querystring in the manner you have described is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: looks like bad idea - query string is the approach. Keeping for reference: local storage as well as script can be disabled, so it needs to be considered when designing any client side detection logic.

---

You can also try to use local storage in browser to prevent infinite redirects. It will allow you to keep url clean from "?isCookie=true" query string. Note that you need JavaScript enabled for that. If you worried about cookies you should be worried about JavaScript disabled too.

Comment: Just wondering if local storage will end up being something that can be disabled, just like cookies.

Comment: I think so. Also I'd be surprised if there are any people outside industry who know about local storage at all to start with. Cookies and JavaScript are generally known to be "evil", so people may make an effort to disable them.

Answer (score 0):

What I wound up doing (in case someone else tries this) was using a couple of tricks:

- Set up an ASP.NET hidden field control with its value set to false (default - cookies are disabled)
- Used client-side script to check whether cookies are enabled
- *If the cookie gets set, cookies are enabled.* In this case I use a jQuery call to change the value of the hidden field from false to true
- Server-side, if the value of the hidden field is true, the page does the redirect. Otherwise, it just continues processing the page.

If the user has Javascript disabled, the value of the hidden field remains false, so the page is still rendered only once.

Thanks for letting me talk through it and getting me thinking!